# Angular Directive doesn't load template in IE8

Tags: angularjs

Angular version: 1.2.6

All of my directives (example below) fail to make a request for their templates in IE8. I've got Charles proxy running to see the network requests and it doesn't make a request. I've tried changing the path to the templates. I'm not sure what to do as it works if the content is set using the 'template' property but I can't put all the markup into the directives. That would be rubbish.

```
app.directive('bbContent', function(paths) {
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      replace: true,
      scope: true,
      templateUrl: "/angular/partials/content_main.html"
    };
  });
```

Additional note: It's not just directives I've worked out. IE8 fails to make a request for any resource i.e ng-include doesn't work either.

```
<div ng-include="'/angular/partials/content_main.html'"></div>
```

The only way I can get it to work is using ng-template but that's not what I want to do at the moment. The option below works.

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="/angular/partials/content_main.html">
```